# Unity Issue Shadow Caster 2D

Tags: light

I'm having this issue when working with the new Shadow Caster 2D in Unity.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvUNsYCVeIM&feature=youtu.be

[image]

Comment: Well I can try to explain it a little bit further, but the idea is if someone knows why it doesnt cast a shadow like it supposed to. It has to do with coding. I am not quite sure how to put it into words. Any advice?

Comment: Hi, I recently reported this anomaly to their issue tracker and they have confirmed that it is a bug. Here's the link to the post. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/universal-rp-2d-point-light-is-rendered-incorrectly-when-a-gameobjects-with-shadow-caster-2d-scale-is-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to increase the outer radius and raise the falloff intensity to max to compensate.

Dev told of another temporarely fix, which is to add a vertex to your shadow caster in the middle of each of your sides. I haven't tried it myself yet, as I've found solution 1 sufficient for testing purposes, but i'll probably try it out as some point.

Ultimately its a bug that they will fix it in time.

For futher questions regarding 2d Lights/Shadows I recommend the thread on Unity: [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/experimental-2d-lights-and-shader-graph-support-in-lwrp.683623/page-8)

Comment: Thank you for your help Chris! I've already tried increasing the outer radius and raise the falloff intensity but I didn't like the outcome. 
As soon as I get home from work I'll try adding a vertex, any suggestions on the proper way to do it?